# On click isn't fired on recyclerview in nestedscrollview under coordinatorlayout in Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

There're two dimentional recyvlerview under nested scroll view under coordinator layout. Clicking to RC items isn't firing with coordinator layout, without it firing good. How to solve it?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/main_root"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:clickable="true">

<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/main_nsv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#AB9984"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/main_recycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:context=".activity.MainActivity">


    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

Comment: can you remove the `RecyclerView` from the parent `NestedScrollView`? If so, do it. Also, try removing `android:clickable="true"` from the `CoordinatorLayout`, that may be catching the click action.

Comment: NestedScrollView for hard loading so it's important in there.